# ToC showing the correct page but linking to the wrong page

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

The ToC is not linking to the correct page, the page numbering is correct in the ToC but when I click on the hyperref it takes me the wrong section

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report} % Default font size is 12pt, it can be changed here
\usepackage{geometry} % Required to change the page size to A4
\geometry{a4paper} % Set the page size to be A4 as opposed to the default US Letter
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including pictures
\usepackage{float} % Allows putting an [H] in \begin{figure} to specify the exact location of the figure
\usepackage{wrapfig} % Allows in-line images
\graphicspath{{../figures/}}  % Specifies the directory where pictures are stored
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\linespread{1.2} % Line spacing
%\setlength\parindent{0pt} % Uncomment to remove all indentation from paragraphs
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=red,linkcolor=black,bookmarks=true]{hyperref} % makes color citations
\usepackage{indentfirst} %indent all the first lines of an sentance
\usepackage[sort&compress,round,semicolon,authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} % only number chapters 
\usepackage{forest} % to create pretty diagrams
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
  my rounded corners/.append style={rounded corners=2pt},
}
\colorlet{linecol}{black!75}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\bookmarksetup{
  numbered,
  open
}

%used to center the chapter headings and decrease the space before and after the heading which is unreasonable in the normal setting
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries\centering}
  {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{10pt}{\Huge}
  \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{20pt} 

%\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

% document begin
\begin{document}
```

Please feel free to comment on the general code to, I just started using latex.

Comment: Maybe one more compilation will help ?

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) how are we suppose to test this when the MWE depends in files we do not have access to?

Comment: I tired compiling more than once a couple of times. I'm a noob -  what would be appropriate as a MWE? I thought the order of the packages or the use of \addcontentsline might be the problem (although I uncommented it and it was still not correct), hence the reason I only posted that.

Comment: A MWE should be compilable by itself and should show the problem. Referring to files that you don't provide (except those that come with standard TeX distributions) is not helpful: either remove the reference if the problems still remains after removal, or include the file if its contents is essential.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll make sure I add a adequate MWE next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it was the order of the packages that mixed things up. I think the latex document still compiled with the defult layout and spacing. I moved my layout setup:

```
  \usepackage{titlesec}
     \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
     {\normalfont\huge\bfseries\centering}
     {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{10pt}{\Huge}
     \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{20pt}
```

higher up in my package list and it's fine now.